# Getting error "package X does not exist" in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.*; ...    

ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add("Item");
```

This is my Java code.  The final line gets the error: "package stringList does not exist".

How can I get rid of this error and start adding items to my list? I can only imagine I'm missing something very simple.  Thanks in advance.

Partially per request, below is my whole code.  It's incomplete, but I'm stuck on the above problem.

```
package gorobot_m5d25y2013;

//import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Engine {  // The Engine will show the best positions on the board given a particular board setup.

    // Some project-wide constants and variables.
    final int BLACK = 1;      // Black go pieces... black goes first in the game of go, unless black has
    // a 2 stone or greater handicap.
    final int WHITE = 2;      // White go pieces... usually goes second in the game.
    final int EMPTY = 0;      // An empty space, no piece is on it.
    final int VIRTUAL = -1;   // This is a space outside of the board that can never be played on,
    // but is useful if there's ever an issue of checking something for
    // the board which would normally be out of bounds.
    final int BLACKS_TURN = 1;
    final int WHITES_TURN = 2;
    final int BOARD_SIZE = 19;              // Access with Global.BOARD_SIZE ... this is the width of the board.
    final int VIRTUAL_BOARD_BORDER = 10;    // This is the width of the empty space around each of the four sides of the board.
    int whoseTurn;                          // 1 is blacks turn, 2 is white's turn.
    int totalGames = 0;
    int blackWins = 0;
    static long groupCounter = 1; // Used in inner class group.
    int positionNumber = 1; // Used in inner class group and position.
    int[][] boardValues = new int[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];  // boardValues is the win probability for each position on the board.

    Engine() {
        Board firstMove = new Board();
    }

    int oppositeWhoseTurn() {
        int opposite = 0;
        if (whoseTurn == BLACKS_TURN) {
            opposite = WHITES_TURN;
        }
        if (whoseTurn == WHITES_TURN) {
            opposite = BLACKS_TURN;
        }
        if (opposite == 0) {
            System.out.println("An error with the opposite variable has occured.");
        }
        return opposite;
    }

    int regPos(int boardPosition) { // This Regulates Position-Ex. takes any of the normal board positions, for example,
        // 1-19, and sets it to the virtual, larger board. So a Position 1 move will be position 9 with a 10 space buffer.
        int realBoardPosition = (boardPosition + (VIRTUAL_BOARD_BORDER - 1));
        return realBoardPosition;
    }

    class Board { // The board is composed of positions and groups.  At first it is 2 groups, the real and the virtual

        int virtualPlusRegularBoardSize = (BOARD_SIZE + (VIRTUAL_BOARD_BORDER * 2));
        Position[][] point = new Position[virtualPlusRegularBoardSize][virtualPlusRegularBoardSize];
        Group food = new Group();

        Board() {
            for (int horizontal = 0; horizontal < virtualPlusRegularBoardSize; horizontal++) {
                for (int vertical = 0; vertical < virtualPlusRegularBoardSize; vertical++) {
                    point[horizontal][vertical] = new Position(horizontal, vertical);
                }
            }
            for (int horizontal = 1; horizontal <= BOARD_SIZE; horizontal++) {
                for (int vertical = 1; vertical <= BOARD_SIZE; vertical++) {
                    point[regPos(horizontal)][regPos(vertical)].setType(EMPTY);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Group { // Each Group is composed of positions

        long groupNumber;
        int sizeOfGroup = 1;
        Integer[] ints = new Integer[1];
        ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        stringList.add ("Item");


        //List<Position> positionList = new ArrayList<>();

        //positionList.size ();

        //positionList.add ();
        //positionList.remove("F");

        Group() {
            groupNumber = groupCounter;
            groupCounter++;
        }

        void setGroupNumber(int newGroupNumber) {
            sizeOfGroup = newGroupNumber;
        }

        long getGroupNumber() {
            return groupNumber;
        }

        void setSizeOfGroup(int newGroupSize) {
            sizeOfGroup = newGroupSize;
        }

        int getSizeOfGroup() {
            return sizeOfGroup;
        }

        void addPositionToGroup(Position point) {
        }
    }

    class Position {    // Each position is either Empty, Black, White, or Virtual.

        int pieceType;  // VIRTUAL means it's not even a board position, at first all spaces are like this...
        // but eventually, the positions on the actual board will all be empty - 0, and then
        // will start filling with black - 1 and white - 2 pieces.
        boolean legalMove; // This tells us whether this space is a legal move.
        int numberOfLiberties = 2;
        int virtualHorizontal;
        int virtualVertical;

        Position() {
            pieceType = VIRTUAL;
            legalMove = false;
        }

        Position(int horizontal, int vertical) {
            pieceType = VIRTUAL;
            legalMove = true;
            virtualHorizontal = horizontal;
            virtualVertical = vertical;
        }

        void setType(int setType) {
            pieceType = setType;
            ////// Add in here the 4 surrounding sides and make those these variables accessible from the piece class.
            if (setType == BLACK) {
            }
            if (setType == WHITE) {
            }
        }

        int getType() {
            return pieceType;
        }
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @author Eric Martin
 */
public class GoRobot_m5d25y2013 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Engine firstEngine = new Engine();
    }
}
```

And these are my errors:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method "<error>" in class gorobot_m5d25y2013/Engine$Group has illegal signature "(Ljava/lang/Object;)LstringList/add;"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at gorobot_m5d25y2013.Engine$Board.<init>(GoRobot_m5d25y2013.java:73)
    at gorobot_m5d25y2013.Engine.<init>(GoRobot_m5d25y2013.java:46)
    at gorobot_m5d25y2013.GoRobot_m5d25y2013.main(GoRobot_m5d25y2013.java:181)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: From your given code, the error should not arise. Probably there's somewhere else in the code where this error arise. Post the whole stacktrace and the relevant code to evaluate it.

Comment: You could be trying to update the `stringList` outside of a `method` or `static` initialization section.  Only variables can be declared (and initialised) out side of these sections.  For better support, consider providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Luiggi, I added my whole code and error output above.  Hopefully that's the same thing as a stack trace.

Comment: Looks great, thank you.  I guess my experience in C++ is making me forget that I can't write any statements other than variable statements outside of constructors and methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your edit, the problem is that you're calling `stringList.add("Item");` in the class definition. The execution of methods from your class fields should be done inside a method. In your case, looks like this line should be inside your class constructor:

```
class Group { // Each Group is composed of positions
    //fields definitions (and probably initialization of fields)...
    //field declaration
    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //this code can't be here
    //stringList.add("Item");

    Group() {
        //move it here
        stringList.add("Item");
        //...
    }

    //rest of code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is not generating any error and I think you have not put it in the class.You can try this.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class One {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<String> stringList=new ArrayList<String>();
        stringList.add("Europe");
        System.out.println(stringList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an object of Group.
Then use that object to access the list.

In main method try

```
 Group g = new Group();
 g.stringList.add("item");
```